# React update or add to an array of objects in useState when a new object is received

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Occasionally a `newItem` is received from a WebSocket and gets saved to useState with `saveNewItem`

this then kicks off the `useEffect` block as expected.

Update. If there is an object in the `closeArray`  with the same `openTime` as the `newItem` I want to replace that object in `closeArray` with the `newItem` because it will have a new `close`

Add. If there isn't an object in the `closeArray` with the same open time as `newItem` I want to push the new item into the array.

Remove. And finally, if the array gets longer than 39 objects I want to remove of the first item.

If I add `closeArray` to the array of `useEffect` dependencies I'm going to create a nasty loop, if I don't add it `closeArray` isn't going to get updated.

I want `usEffect` to only fire off when `newItem` changes and not if `closeArray` changes, but I still want to get and set data to `closeArray` in `useEffect`

```
interface CloseInterface {
  openTime: number;
  closeTime: number;
  close: number;
}
function App() {
  const [newItem, saveNewItem] = useState<CloseInterface>();
  const [closeArray, saveCloseArray] = useState<CloseInterface[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (newItem) {
      let found = false;
      let arr = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < closeArray.length; i++) {
        if (closeArray[i].openTime === newItem.openTime) {
          found = true;
          arr.push(newItem);
        } else {
          arr.push(closeArray[i]);
        }
      }
      if (found === false) {
        arr.push(newItem)
      }
      if (arr.length === 39) arr.shift();
      saveCloseArray(arr);
    }
  }, [newItem]); // <--- I need to add closeArray but it will make a yucky loop
```

If I do add `closeArray` to the `useEffect` dependancy array I get the error...

```
index.js:1 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
    in App (at src/index.tsx:9)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.tsx:8)
```

if I don't add `closeArray` to the `useEffect` dependancy array I get this error...

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'closeArray'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

the second `useEffect` block gets the initial data for `closeArray` and listens to a WebSocket that updates `newItem` as it arrives.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getDetails = async () => {
      const params = new window.URLSearchParams({
        symbol: symbol.toUpperCase(),
        interval
      });
      const url = `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?${params}&limit=39`;
      const response = await fetch(url, { method: "GET" });
      const data = await response.json();
      if (data) {
        const arrayLength = data.length;
        let newcloseArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
          const openTime = data[i][0];
          const closeTime = data[i][6];
          const close = data[i][4];
          newcloseArray.push({ openTime, closeTime, close });
        }
        saveCloseArray(newcloseArray);
        const ws = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws");
        ws.onopen = () =>
          ws.send(
            JSON.stringify({
              method: "SUBSCRIBE",
              params: [`${symbol}@kline_${interval}`],
              id: 1
            })
          );
        ws.onmessage = e => {
          const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
          const value = data.k;
          if (value) {
            const openTime = value.t;
            const closeTime = value.T;
            const close = value.c;
            saveNewItem({ openTime, closeTime, close });
          }
        };
      }
    };
    getDetails();
  }, [symbol, interval]);
```

Comment: This looks fine as it is. Is not having `closeArray` in `useEffect`'s second argument causing any problems?

Comment: yes react throws an error in the console asking me to add it to the dependency array

Comment: In that case, please add the error to your question.

Comment: added thanks for the improvement suggestion

Comment: Ok, good that you've added the error when `closeArray` is in the dependency array. What about when it isn't? Is there an error then? If so please add it in as well.

Comment: You're always calling `saveCloseArray` with a new array object, so that's why it always rerenders when you have `closeArray` as a dependency. You probably want to use the function updater syntax so you don't need the dependency, and basically just update the single entry in the array that needs to change. This operation is also better suited for a `useCallback`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to better write your code, you can make use of state updater callback method, so that even if you don't pass closeArray to the useEffect and it will sstill have updated values on each run of useEffect

```
function App() {
  const [newItem, saveNewItem] = useState<CloseInterface>();
  const [closeArray, saveCloseArray] = useState<CloseInterface[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (newItem) {
      let found = false;

      saveCloseArray(prevCloseArray => {
         let arr = [];
         for (let i = 0; i < prevCloseArray.length; i++) {
            if (prevCloseArray[i].openTime === newItem.openTime) {
              found = true;
              arr.push(newItem);
            } else {
              arr.push(prevCloseArray[i]);
            }
          }
          if (found === false) {
            arr.push(newItem)
          }
          if (arr.length === 39) arr.shift();
          return arr;
      })
    }
  }, [newItem]);
```

Comment: I gave it a try and I get the error ` Line 56:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'closeArray'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'saveCloseArray(c => ...)' if you only need 'closeArray' in the 'saveCloseArray' call  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Comment: @Bill My mistake, updated my answer, instead of `closeArray` you had to use `prevCloseArray`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `useCallback` to save your new array with the updated item, like so:

```
const [closeArray, saveCloseArray] = useState<CloseInterface[]>([]);
const updateEntry = useCallback(newItem => {
  saveCloseArray(oldCloseArray => oldCloseArray.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc.push(item.openTime === newItem.openTime ? newItem : item);
    return acc;
  }, []));
}, []);
```

You'd then apply the callback function to your button or div or whatever component is being generated, EG

```
return (
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(item => <button key={`${item}`} onClick={() => updateEntry(item)}>Click me</button>)
);
```

Comment: Derek, thanks for this, I don't have a button, the new item is coming from a WebSocket that then saves the new item to `saveNewItem` can I just add `newItem` to the dependency array of `updateEntry` in your answer?

Comment: no, you would simply use `updateEntry` in the handler of your websocket event. Please post as much of your relevant code as possible, makes it easier to help with the right solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If the only reason you have `newItem` is to update `closeArray` I would consider moving that functionality into the `useEffect` that utilizes WebSocket. You can still use `newItem` if you need to do something in addition to just updating `closeArray`, like showing an alert or a popup, for instance. Here's what I mean:

```
interface CloseInterface {
    openTime: number;
    closeTime: number;
    close: number;
}

function App() {
    const [newItem, saveNewItem] = useState<CloseInterface>();
    const [closeArray, saveCloseArray] = useState<CloseInterface[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Do something when newItem changes, e.g. show alert
        if (newItem) {

        }
    }, [newItem]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Work with the new item
        const precessNewItem = (item = {}) => {
            let found = false;
            let arr = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < closeArray.length; i++) {
                if (closeArray[i].openTime === item.openTime) {
                    found = true;
                    arr.push(item);
                } else {
                    arr.push(closeArray[i]);
                }
            }

            if (found === false) {
                arr.push(item)
            }

            if (arr.length === 39) arr.shift();

            saveCloseArray(arr);

            // save new item 
            saveNewItem(item);
        };

        const getDetails = async () => {
            const params = new window.URLSearchParams({
                symbol: symbol.toUpperCase(),
                interval
            });

            const url = `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?${params}&limit=39`;
            const response = await fetch(url, { method: "GET" });
            const data = await response.json();

            if (data) {
                const arrayLength = data.length;
                let newcloseArray = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                    const openTime = data[i][0];
                    const closeTime = data[i][6];
                    const close = data[i][4];
                    newcloseArray.push({ openTime, closeTime, close });
                }

                saveCloseArray(newcloseArray);
                const ws = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws");

                ws.onopen = () =>
                    ws.send(
                        JSON.stringify({
                            method: "SUBSCRIBE",
                            params: [`${symbol}@kline_${interval}`],
                            id: 1
                        })
                    );

                ws.onmessage = e => {
                    const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
                    const value = data.k;

                    if (value) {
                        const openTime = value.t;
                        const closeTime = value.T;
                        const close = value.c;

                        // process new item
                        processNewItem({ openTime, closeTime, close });
                    }
                };
            }
        };
        getDetails();
    }, [symbol, interval, closeArray]); // add closeArray here
 }
```